# Patch Value in cdkDragDrop

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-drag-drop, patchvalue

having a problem in patch value I cant populate the data in the cdkdragdrop, or im missing something in my HTML under cdkdrop? hoping someone could help me. or is there any other way around for patching value in cdkdrop  list

.HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="column">
        <div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let process of processess; let i = index" cdkDrag>
            <div class="col-sm-10 process-container">
                <div class=" process">{{ process }}  </div>
                <div class="order">{{ stepNo[i] + 1 }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                
            <button mat-icon-button>
                <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteItem(i)">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="saveAllData()">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

.TS

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.fg = this.fb.group({ 
      isALLLocation: [false,Boolean],
      processId: [0],
      processName: [''],
      processType: [''],
      locationType: [''],
      dformArray: this.fb.array([this.CreateDformArray({ processId: 0, stepNo:0, roleId: 0, permitModuleId: 0 })])          
    })
}

CreateDformArray(item: processStepsDTO): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    processId: [item.processId],
    roleId: [item.roleId],
    stepNo:[item.stepNo],
    permitModuleId: [item.permitModuleId],
  });
}


editData(Details: processDTO) {
  this.iData = Details;

  this.fg.patchValue({
    processId: this.iData.processId,
    processName: this.iData.processName,
    processType: this.iData.processType,
    locationType: this.iData.locationType
  });


  while (this.processSteps.length !== 0) {
    this.processSteps.removeAt(0);
  }

  this.iData.processSteps.forEach((step: processStepsDTO) => {
    this.processSteps.push(this.fb.group({
      processId: [step.processId],
      roleId: [step.roleId],
      stepNo: [step.stepNo],
      permitModuleId: [step.permitModuleId]
    }));
  });
}
```

having a problem in patch value I cant populate the data in the cdkdragdrop, or im missing something in my HTML under cdkdrop? hoping someone could help me. or is there any other way around for patching value in cdkdrop  list